# Designer code in Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, user-interface

I created a UI using XAML, in windows phone 7. I want to know if this code exists as C# code in some file and if it is so, where is the designer code, generated by the xaml?

Comment: Actually, I designed a stackpanel, and wanted to use the properties code to generate the same stackpanel programatically

Comment: @acebox don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in any of the XAML based technologies. You have an XY problem here. Post another question with your current XAML and your specific need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create `StackPanel` programmatically, you can do it by "mimicking" the XAML version.

For example, the following XAML:

```
<StackPanel Foreground="White"
            Margin="12,0,0,0">
</StackPanel>
```

can be created with the following C# code:

```
var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
stackPanel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush("White");
stackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(12,0,0,0);
```

Without knowing what your `StackPanel` looks like, I cannot offer you any tipss.

---

I must wonder why you want to do that? XAML is generally far better to design than doing it in via code. Not to mention it is cleaner and is adaptable to MVVM which is the best solution for your application.

If you offer some more details, I can offer precise advice.

Comment: Right...I wanted to use different types of stackpanels in my pivot page applicaton...say for example...a stackpanel containing text and image, the image can be below the text, on its right, or on its left. And i want to do this randomly...implying that any stackpanel can come up at anytime (stackpanels are in a listbox). Can I do it using XAML? I had created a derived class from the stackpanel class, and was thinking of doing it dynamically rather than use MVVM (by setting itemssource of the listbox as the list of objects of my derived class).

Comment: Also manually writing the property setting code is quite tedious as my stackpanel has many children.

Comment: Well, of course it is tedious :D That is why you write it in XAML ;) How random do you want your stack panels to be? Do you have a fixed set of pregenerated StackPanels or do you want to generate completely new StackPanels?

Comment: If you have a finite set, you can use `DataTemplateSelector` for that.

Comment: Well my designs are fixed (there are 3 kinds of panels as mentioned above)

Comment: Then use `DataTemplateSelector` to choose randomly from three `DataTemplates`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create code in XAML this code in C# doesn't exist in any file in your project.
The XAML code is changed to object in compilation process.
Here You have great article about this process:

[Article](http://geekswithblogs.net/RizwanSharp/archive/2007/12/31/deep-dive-into-xaml-part-2-of-wpf-learning-series.aspx)

You can create GUI in code behind using objects like this:

```
var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
```